# Spark read from Teradata view which has column with Title

Tags: scala, apache-spark, teradata

I want to try read from Teradata using Spark.

I have a Teradata view from one table which has column(order_id) with title( "ORDER ID") column name.

So while using spark it is giving me following error.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.08] [Error 5628] [SQLState HY000] Column ORDER ID not found in ST.

```
 val Query  = "(select order_id from table sample 100) ST ";

 var reader = sparkSession.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:teradata://xx/charset=xx, DBS_PORT=xx, TMODE=TERA, user=xx, password=xx")
      .option("dbtable", Query);

    reader.load().show(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, a title is just a way to change the display name of a column when returning the results.  In your query you'd still need to reference the actual column name or alias.

That being said, if `"ORDER ID"` is actually an alias for the `order_id` column, then you just reference it like that in your query with double quotes: `select "ORDER ID" from table sample 100`

Just make sure you properly escape the quotes when setting the `Query` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the option "column_name" -> "on", to query using the columnNames instead of the titles (it should work for TD drivers >=16) [I've tested it with 17]

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .options(Map(
    "url" -> tdURL,
    "user" -> yourUser,
    "password" -> yourPw,
    "dbtable" ->  table,
    "strict_names" -> "off",
    "column_name" -> "on",
    "driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"))
  .load()
```

Comment: With TeraJDBC 16.20.00.13, I needed to add `,column_name=on` to url to make it work